# Change background color when the cursor is hovering on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, mouse

I want the background color of the page to change when the mouse cursor is on a `<button>` but not if it's clicked.

```js
jQuery.fn.mouseIsOver = function () {
  if($(this[0]).is(":hover"))
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};   
 
if($("b1").mouseIsOver()===true)
{
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1", type="button">1</button>
```

I copied that `jQuery.fn` from somewhere but I don't know how to make that `if(cond)`.

I want to check if mouse is hovering on the button, and if so, change the background color.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is that the if statement is only executed once. In order to continuously check whether the button is hovered you'll need to use an event listener.

Comment: Please check the green `check` sign next to an answer which you used

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery needed for this if you're predominantly using native JS in your code. All you need is a `mouseover` event listener.

```js
document.getElementById('b1').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#aa0000';
});
```

```html
<button id="b1", type="button">1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to target id, you must begin the selector with # (dieze)

```
$('#b1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#b1" ).mouseover(function() {
  $("div.background").css( "color", "red" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event listeners to your button. No need for the overhead of `jQuery` for this solution.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
});

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "not if it's clicked", but what about this?

```
<button id="theButton">Press Me</button>

<script>
$('#theButton')
    .on('mouseenter', function(event) {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function(event) {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add mouseenter and mouseleave. It's the easiest and good solution. Mousedown and up for moment of being clicked.

```js
document.getElementById('b1').addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#A00';
});

document.getElementById('b1').addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
});


document.getElementById('b1').addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#A00';
});

document.getElementById('b1').addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
});
```

```html
<button id="b1" type="button">1</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.button{
   cursor:pointer;
}
.button:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This is done by just using CSS & We can include other properties in hover braces